# Segmentation error happening in my client code

Tags: c, server, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, client

I'm not really good at programming and I'm experiencing a very frustrating moment, I'm coding a client and server thing, in my client code, there is something that is causing a segmentation error and I don't know what it is :

```
uint16_t recevoir_liste_comptines(int fd)
{
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    char** comptines = NULL;
    uint16_t comptine_count = 0;
    int i;
    ssize_t n = read(fd, buf, 256);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *token=malloc(128*sizeof(char));
    if (token==NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc ici");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    token= strtok(buf, "\n");
    while (token != NULL && comptine_count < MAX_COMPTINES) {
        comptines = realloc(comptines, (comptine_count + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        if (comptines == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        comptines[comptine_count++] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    } 

    // Affiche les comptines à partir du tableau
    for (i = 0; i <= comptine_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n",  comptines[i]);
        free(comptines[i]);
    }
    free(comptines);
    free(token);
    return comptine_count;
}
```

context :  this function has to recieve a buffer that contains a list of titles and displays them, all with returning the number of titles. I've spent hours trying to figure out the problem but i can't know what it is, and i am convinced the problem comes from this function, sometimes ( rare moments) it works just fine, without the error, but mostly the error  is there. I'd be very glad to find help here, thank you!

Comment: That's pretty gnarly code with several issues, but I think this is what is killing you: the `<=` in `for (i = 0; i <= comptine_count; i++)`. It should be `<`. An array of `N` items indexes from `0` to `N - 1`.

Comment: The `free(token);` at the end will also probably blow up.

Comment: Aside: This seems to (attempt to) construct a list of strings, then print them. You could do away with all the memory allocation and just print them as you read them.

Comment: @pmacfarlane you were right about the <=, it solved the segmentation fault issue, but now the problem is that when i first run the client it works fine, then when i do it again ( the server is in an infinite loop), it doesn't read the whole buffer... could the problem be also here ?

Comment: You are calling `free(token);` but that no longer points to memory allocated by `malloc()`. (In fact you immediately leak the memory you allocate by re-assigning `token`.) This invokes undefined behaviour. I cannot predict what your code would do next.

Comment: `token   = strtok(buf, "\n");` will leak token that `malloc()`  above.

Comment: Hint: You don't need to `malloc()` any memory for `token`. It can just be a pointer. Remove the `free(token);` after you remove the `malloc();`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane even after removing free(token) and making token a pointer, the client still fails to read the whole buffer when i run it for the second time, i don't understand why it works perfectly 2 times then it stops working properly, but thank you for solving my segmentation issue !

Comment: @10969_shirazu_ You've not given us enough code to answer that question. Maybe you should post a new question, and try to include a [MRE] that we can examine and run.

Comment: Use gdb when facing this type of errors to figure out what's wrong. Compile your code with the `g` flag and omit any optimizations. e.g. `gcc -g -o main main.c`

Answer (score 2):

1, You supplied a snippet so I build a minimal program with it and it segfaults on the line:

```
   printf("%s\n",  comptines[i]);
```

and indeed as @pmacfarlane this is because the loop condition and should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < comptine_count; i++) {
```

2. Don't allocate space for `token`.  It subsequently leaks when it's overwritten by the result from strtok()`:

```
    char *token=malloc(128*sizeof(char));
    if (token==NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc ici");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

3. Don't `free(token)` as it points to `buf` (at some offset) which is a stack allocated variable.  @pmacfarlane pointed this out as well.
4. Use a temporary variable with `realloc()` otherwise you leak `comptines` on `realloc()` failure.  So instead of:

```
comptines = realloc(comptines, (comptine_count + 1) * sizeof(char*));
```

you want to do:

```
char **tmp = realloc(comptines, (comptine_count + 1) * sizeof(char*));
if(!tmp) {
   // ...
}
comptines = tmp;
```

5. Minimize scope of variables.  In your original program make `int i` a local loop variable.  `comptine_count` is moved to the just before use.
6. The only effect your program has is printing each token counting them so there is no point in storing the strings in `comptines`.

Here's the corresponding program that I ended up with:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 42
#define MAX_COMPTINES 10

uint16_t f(int fd) {
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t n = read(fd, buf, 256);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    uint16_t comptine_count = 0;
    for(; comptine_count < MAX_COMPTINES; comptine_count++) {
        char *token = strtok(comptine_count ? NULL : buf, "\n");
        if(!token)
            break;
        printf("%s\n",  token);
    }

    return comptine_count;
}

int main() {
    int fd = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%hu\n", f(fd));
    close(fd);
}
```